# What do these bars below my inventory at the Deploy screen in Battlefield 3 mean?

Tags: battlefield-3

I've noticed that in the Deploy screen of Battlefield 3, there are all these bars below my various weapons and other associated doodads and specialities that fill up the more I use them. What do they indicate? What happens when they fill up all the way?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bar represents your progress towards the next unlock in that weapon group. The more you use a certain weapon class, vehicle, etc, the more you points you will earn toward an additional unlock in that category. You can see a more detailed view of this progression in your battlelog profile:

[image]

Comment: I'd like to add that the white part of the bar is your exp before this match, the blue part is the exp you've earned during this match, and both put together is your total exp.

Comment: I'd like to further add to this that when you are in-game, at the bottom right of your screen, underneath your currently equipped weapon's ammo counter is a bar which represents your progress torwards the next unlock for that specific weapon.